# How to collect multiple URLs from XHTML

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm really new to XPath and R in general. So I hope my question is not too stupid.

I want to  collect multiple URLs (the searchresults) from a webpage: 
http://www.totaljobs.com/JobSearch/Results.aspx?Keywords=Leadership&LTxt=&Radius=10&RateType=0&JobType1=&CompanyType=&PageNum=

```
<h2>
    <a id="resultsList_rptSearchResults_ctl00_lnkJobTitle" property="title" href="/JobSearch/JobDetails.aspx?JobId=63057920&amp;Keywords=Leadership&amp;LTxt=&amp;Radius=10&amp;RateType=0&amp;JobType1=&amp;CompanyType=&amp;PageNum=2">Adult Social Care - Senior Leadership (Mental Health)</a>
</h2>
```

The code i used is the following:

```
pageNum <- seq(1:10)
url <- paste0("http://www.totaljobs.com/JobSearch/Results.aspx?Keywords=Leadership&LTxt=&Radius=10&RateType=0&JobType1=&CompanyType=&PageNum=") 

urls <- paste0(url, pageNum) 
allLinks <- list() 
for (url in urls) { 
  doc <- getURLContent(url)[[1]]
  xmlDoc <- htmlParse(doc) 
  xPath <- "//*[contains(concat( ' ', @class, ' ' ), concat( ' ', 'hd', ))]"
  linkToArticle <- XML::getNodeSet(xmlDoc, xPath) 
  linkUrls <- sapply(linkToArticle, function (x) XML::xmlGetAttr(x, "href"))  
  allLinks <- c(allLinks, linkUrls) }

print(length(allLinks))
```

The result from print(length(allLinks)) is mostly: 
[[Number]]
Null

I tried multiple xpath commands (at least i think this is were the problem is) including the one which is displayed in the code. I also tried this

```
//*[(@id = "resultsList_rptSearchResults_ctl01_lnkJobTitle")]
```

But it only gives me result x from every URL of the 1-10 pages.

If someone could lead me in the right direction would be amazing.

Comment: Just make sure you read http://www.totaljobs.com/terms-and-conditions#general thoroughly before proceeding with your endeavors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where almost there

```
library(RCurl);library(XML)

pageNum <- seq(1:10)
url <- paste0("http://www.totaljobs.com/JobSearch/Results.aspx?Keywords=Leadership&LTxt=&Radius=10&RateType=0&JobType1=&CompanyType=&PageNum=") 
urls <- paste0(url, pageNum) 

allPages <- lapply(urls, function(x) getURLContent(x)[[1]])
xmlDocs <- lapply(allPages, function(x) XML::htmlParse(x))

ResultsPerPage <- 19

# Essentially this is the difference from your code
xPath <- paste0("//*[@id='resultsList_rptSearchResults_ctl", 
                ifelse(nchar(0:ResultsPerPage)==1, paste0("0", (0:ResultsPerPage)), (0:ResultsPerPage)),
               "_lnkJobTitle']")

linksToArticle <- unlist(lapply(xmlDocs, function(x) XML::getNodeSet(x, xPath)))
linkUrls <- lapply(linksToArticle, function (x) XML::xmlGetAttr(x, "href")) 

#Remove all objects except for linkUrls
rm(list=ls()[!(ls()=="linkUrls")])

length(linkUrls)
print(paste0("http://www.totaljobs.com", linkUrls))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Really really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory Hadleyverse version:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(pbapply)

base_url <- "http://www.totaljobs.com/JobSearch/Results.aspx?Keywords=Leadership&LTxt=&Radius=10&RateType=0&JobType1=&CompanyType=&PageNum=%d"

unlist(pblapply(1:10, function(i) {

  # grab the page
  pg <- html_session(sprintf(base_url, i), 
                     user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.15 Safari/537.36"))

  # extract the links
  pg %>% 
    html_nodes("a[id^='resultsList_rptSearchResults'][href^='/JobSearch']") %>% 
    html_attr("href")

})) -> links
```

This uses CSS selectors instead of XPath and `pblapply` gets you progress bars for free. I needed to use the `user_agent` since it was restricting me (403) otherwise.

Comment: Nice, i didn't know about the `user_agent` that's why i used `RCurl`